# Incompatible jars detected between client and server

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I would like to setup Apache Phoenix on top of HBase on Cloudera CDH 5.2.

I downloaded latest release (4.2.2) of Phoenix and put the *server* jar file into a directory on each region server (I did not modify the master).

Then I changed the `hbase-env.sh` file to point to the file with the `HBASE_CLASSPATH_PREFIX` variable.

When I run the following commang:

```
hbase classpath
```

The phoenix serer-jar is reported in the list.

From the *master* machine, when I try using `./sqlline.py quorumserver` I get the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ERROR 2006 (INT08): Incompatible jars detected between client and server. Ensure that phoenix.jar is put on the classpath of HBase in every region server: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException: No registered coprocessor service found for name MetaDataService in region SYSTEM.CATALOG,,1421861120199.56856673d5cff02b55b9ff5955485dba.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:5579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execServiceOnRegion(HRegionServer.java:3416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execService(HRegionServer.java:3398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:29591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionCode$Factory$1.newException(SQLExceptionCode.java:337)
    at org.apache.phoenix.exception.SQLExceptionInfo.buildException(SQLExceptionInfo.java:133)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.checkClientServerCompatibility(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:919)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.ensureTableCreated(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:817)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.createTable(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1126)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.DelegateConnectionQueryServices.createTable(DelegateConnectionQueryServices.java:110)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTableInternal(MetaDataClient.java:1590)
    at org.apache.phoenix.schema.MetaDataClient.createTable(MetaDataClient.java:568)
    at org.apache.phoenix.compile.CreateTableCompiler$2.execute(CreateTableCompiler.java:175)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:271)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$2.call(PhoenixStatement.java:263)
    at org.apache.phoenix.call.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:53)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeMutation(PhoenixStatement.java:261)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.executeUpdate(PhoenixStatement.java:1043)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1551)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$9.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1520)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:77)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:1520)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:162)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.connect(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:126)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:133)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.connect(SqlLine.java:4650)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$DatabaseConnection.getConnection(SqlLine.java:4701)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3942)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$Commands.connect(SqlLine.java:3851)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at sqlline.SqlLine$ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(SqlLine.java:2810)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:817)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:633)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:680)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.mainWithInputRedirection(SqlLine.java:441)
    at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:424)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException: No registered coprocessor service found for name MetaDataService in region SYSTEM.CATALOG,,1421861120199.56856673d5cff02b55b9ff5955485dba.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:5579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execServiceOnRegion(HRegionServer.java:3416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execService(HRegionServer.java:3398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:29591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:285)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1567)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:93)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel$1.call(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.callExecService(RegionCoprocessorRpcChannel.java:96)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CoprocessorRpcChannel.callMethod(CoprocessorRpcChannel.java:51)
    at org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.generated.MetaDataProtos$MetaDataService$Stub.getVersion(MetaDataProtos.java:7996)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$3.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:894)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$3.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:886)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable$16.call(HTable.java:1542)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException): org.apache.hadoop.hbase.exceptions.UnknownProtocolException: No registered coprocessor service found for name MetaDataService in region SYSTEM.CATALOG,,1421861120199.56856673d5cff02b55b9ff5955485dba.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegion.execService(HRegion.java:5579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execServiceOnRegion(HRegionServer.java:3416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.HRegionServer.execService(HRegionServer.java:3398)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:29591)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:114)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:94)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:1452)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1656)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(RpcClient.java:1714)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.execService(ClientProtos.java:29924)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.execService(ProtobufUtil.java:1563)
    ... 14 more
```

What else do I have to change in order to making it work ?

Comment: Hi, which combination you finally used: cdh+phoenix versions? Thanks!

Comment: I was able to setup some combinations of hbase/phoenix. See my docker containers (nerdammer/hbase-phoenix).

Comment: hbase-phoenix/dockerfile not good at docker, can you point me to that sh scripts. Tried to search for "CDH", no luck? BWT, right now I'm running CDH 5.2.0 + phoenix 4.3.1, looks like its working!

Comment: @Capacytron Even though it seems  been quite sometimes past, I am using apache-phoenix-4.14.0-cdh5.13.2 with cdh5.16.2 works

Answer (score 2):

You can try solutions from this links with similar issues, maybe some of them will be helpful:

1) https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/phoenix-hbase-user/f-81YhjfaJI/WHY8IQWJYC0J

> The root reason is because the phoenix jar misses permissions.

2) https://www.mail-archive.com/user@phoenix.apache.org/msg00068.html

> Thanks Everyone,
>
> I solve this problem for changing imported jar name.

3) https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PHOENIX-1148

> I received the same error after I lost a RegionServer unexpectedly.
>   The SYSTEM.CATALOG table did not transfer to another RegionServer even
>   after restarting the HBase Master. I fixed this problem by running
>   hbck against a working node. For example: sudo -u hbase hbase hbck
>   -fix

Answer (score 0):

make sure you didn't make stupid mistakes.

like my case, I put the jar under `lib/hbase` instead of should be `lib/hbase/lib` under CDH cluster.

seriously, I was planning to upgrade my cluster.